# Time Date Objects JavaScript getUTCMilliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, time, utc

From the Chrome console:

```
Me:    var dateObj = new Date("2013-04-14 11:48");
undefined
Me:    dateObj
Sun Apr 14 2013 11:48:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
Me:    dateObj.getUTCMilliseconds();
0
```

Can anyone tell me why these Date functions aren't working? I want to take a date string and turn it into UTC milliseconds. As you can see I passed the string to the Date constructor, then applied the function getUTCMilliseconds() to the returned date object. Why is it returning zero??

Comment: You probably want getTime.

Comment: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds() also returns a nonsense answer (integer value in the hundreds instead of trillions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [JavaScript Date valueOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp).

> Return the primitive value of a Date object:

```
dateObj.valueOf()
1365929280000
```

Answer (score 5):

The result is correct - the understanding of the function name is wrong (as was mine).

[`Date.getUTCMilliseconds()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcmilliseconds.asp) is defined to *return the millisecond part of the date* in the same way that `getMinutes()` returns the minutes stored in the object (in your example, that would return 48 minutes).

---

To clarify, with respect to your date `[2013-04-14 11:48]` the various parts are:

- `getFullYear()` === 2013
- `getDate()` === 14
- `getSeconds()` === 0 (because your date string defines a whole number of minutes)
- `getMilliseconds()` === 0 (for the same reason)

A counter-example may be `[2017-11-15 16:53:10.78]`:

- `getSeconds()` === 10
- `getMilliseconds()` === 78

[The functions on `Date` are laid out nicely on the W3Schools page here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

---

I looks like you were after the **Unix timestamp valu**e (which is what I wanted when Google brought me here).

- [`Date.getTime()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) will return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01

Luckily this is the underlying value in the current implementations, [which is why the other answer works so nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29143481/383414).